# iOS Swift 3 performSelector onMainThread

Tags: ios, swift

I used this line in Objective-C

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(importComplete)
withObject: nil waitUntilDone: YES];
```

I have tried to convert the above line to any number of variants but have not found anything that will compile.  My current attempt is as follows:

```
performSelector (onMainThread: #selector(importComplete), withObject:nil, waitUntilDone: false)
```

I have not been able to get my change to compile. The above change delivers the message

> "Use of unresolved identifier `performSelector`.

I've read everything I can find on this method and it appears to be a mess in Swift 3 anyway, but I'm just learning the language and I've wasted a lot of time on what should be a simple syntax.

Can anyone make a suggestion here?

TIA

Comment: In which class you're calling performSelector?

Comment: Did you implement `importComplete` method?

Comment: I did implement importComplete.  Please see comment on answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is not in `withObject` it is in `with`

try this

```
performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(importComplete), with: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
```

and called  the method as

```
func importComplete() {
    //
    print("Hello World")
}
```

**output**
[image]

Comment: There are multiple answers that would have worked.  In the end, I found an error above in the source file that was contributing to the compilation issue, and I got a clean compile with your suggestion plus fixing the item above.  Thanks to all respondents.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options may be:

```
let selector = NSSelectorFromString("importComplete")
perform(selector, on: Thread.main, with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

or

```
let selector = NSSelectorFromString("importComplete")
perform(selector, on: Thread.main, with: nil, waitUntilDone: true, modes: nil)
```

Depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to perform an operation on `main` thread

```
performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(performOperation), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

Your selector method

```
func performOperation() {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your function like,

```
func importComplete()  {


}
```

then you can do,

```
   self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(ViewController.importComplete), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

where `ViewController` is your current class!